# Sidewall Damage. Should I replace this tire?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

IS it safe to drive with this tire?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Oh hell yes replace it Now!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, replace it - it may not look as if it has damaged the plies but serious damage is not always visible - but can be catastrophic...

Safety for you and others...

Edit: as for the question in the body : NO don't drive on it...

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the tire replaced asap. A blowout while driving can cause you to loose control over the vehicle. Drive slowly and with both hands on the steering on your way to the shop.
2. Also get your rim inspected. May be warped.

Comment: A tyre with serious sidewall damage should not be driven on at all - change it for the spare, then drive to the shop.